# Did the characters ever leave Peregrine Island?

Tags: the-a-list

We know that all the main characters, Mags excluded, were either campers or (in Dave's case) a counselor at a camp on Peregrine Island the year before the events of the first season.
We also know that their memories of this were taken away, and they believed that it was their first time on the island. However, the timeline of whether they left or not seems confusing.

In favor of them never having left:

- In the second season, we see Amber apparently erase their memories at a funeral service for Midge. The service would probably have been held shortly after Midge's death, and it would be strange if she had let them leave the island after that.
- If they did leave and not return until the next summer, it would have been ***truly bizarre*** for *everyone* to want to go back to an island where one of their fellow campers had died, and it strains credulity that their families would send them to a camp that had closed the previous year.

In favor of them having left:

- If the funeral service for Midge was right after the end of the first year's summer camp, then they would have been on the island for months before the end of the first season. Amber could have erased their memories *again*, but that is not hinted at on the show.
- We do see the characters arrive on a ferry in the first episode (but that could be part of Amber's illusions, since Mia's friend says that ferries no longer go there).
- When Mia called her friend, the latter would presumably have freaked out after getting a call from a friend whom she hadn't seen in a year, instead of reacting normally.
- Mags says that the other researchers told her that Amber was heading to the island. It would be slightly odd if they had moved her from the Lockwell Institute on the island, and stranger still if everyone else had been left there during the interim.

So did they leave the island between the summer camp and the second, or did they stay on the island?

Comment: The more I think about this, the more confused I get. They *have* to have left the island between one camp and the next, else someone would have come looking for them. But if their memories had been erased at a funeral for Midge on the island, why were there no awkward conversations between Mia and her parents afterward about the death of her best friend, whom she would not have remembered?

Comment: You might want to note that the second season of Baywatch Nights went from a detective agency set in a nightclub to a paranormal investigation team. Second seasons don't always make consistent sense

Comment: @Valorum - The second season makes it more obvious, but the basic tension is still there in the first season. As far as I can tell (which is why I am asking), even considering only the first season, either Amber kept them on the island for a year, with family, friends, and secretive institutes apparently unconcerned, or *every camper* voluntarily returned to the island where their friend had died for a summer camp that had been canceled, on a ferry that no longer ran, presumably with the support of their families.

Answer (score -1):

Yes they left and came back. Dr Shaw told their parents the suffered memory loss can be healed by returning to the island.

Comment: Can you offer any specific evidence to back this up?